# Tuning socket connect call timeout

Tags: winapi, sockets, timeout, connect

Is there any way in a Win32 environment to "tune" the timeout on a socket `connect()` call?  Specifically, I would like to increase the timeout length.  The sockets in use are non-blocking.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

If you're in non-blocking mode after [`connect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737625(VS.85).aspx), you normally use [`select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141(VS.85).aspx) to wait till I/O is ready. This function has a parameter for specifying the timeout value and will return 0 in case of a timeout.

Comment: No, this is not possible. The default connect timeout can be decreased but not increased.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO socket options to set timeouts for any socket operations. Example:

```
struct timeval timeout;      
timeout.tv_sec = 10;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

if (setsockopt (sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
            sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt failed\n");

if (setsockopt (sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
            sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
    error("setsockopt failed\n");
```

You can also try alarm(). Sample:

```
signal( SIGALRM, connect_alarm ); /* connect_alarm is you signal handler */
alarm( secs ); /* secs is your timeout in seconds */
if ( connect( fd, addr, addrlen ) < 0 )
{
    if ( errno == EINTR ) /* timeout, do something below */
        ...
}
alarm( 0 ); /* cancel the alarm */
```

Comment: Receive and send timeouts have nothing to do with the connection timeout.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. The default connect timeout can be decreased, but not increased.