# multithreading object-oriented socket code with timeout

Tags: c++, sockets, timeout, alarm

We have a nice class that establishes a socket connection and then hits it repeatedly.
If it ever gets a timeout, we want to throw an exception.

What I'd like is an independent timeout for each object.  However, as noted in other posts there is no portable socket timeout code.

[Socket Timeout in C++ Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933122/socket-timeout-in-c-linux)

I am currently doing it with a signal, but this is ugly, because there's a single global variable that points to the current object.  This means this code could not be multithreaded.

Is there any way of establishing a timer in a per-thread way so that each object could run within its own thread?  That seems the cleanest way.  I could build a queue so that they all wait in a critical section, but that's extremely ugly and would impact multithreading performance (and I don't want to anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using async I/O. For example, using [`libevent`](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) or [`asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Just fire up a read operation and a timer on the same dispatching thread (I/O service).